# OpenGL Java Applet without security warnings

Tags: java, security, opengl, applet

I need to make a java applet I can embed in a web page with no security warnings and uses OpenGL.

I have been working with JOGL 1.x so far and the code runs great, however I can't embed it without security warnings, and even then it doesn't run unless you change your java config to allow signed and unsigned code to mix...

I know JOGL 1.x is somewhat abandoned, so what should I use instead? I heard there were lots of problems with 2.x, additionally I think it will require a security warning...

Is there something else I can use to expose OpenGL, that I can use unsigned so there's no warnings?

Comment: "Is there something else I can use to expose OpenGL, that I can use unsigned so there's no warnings?"  AFAIU, nothing short of black magic will achieve that goal.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... it used to work according to the tutorials and documentation that's all out dated now... guess java is no longer a viable option for embedded content using OpenGL.

Comment: @ima737 You could just use JOGL 2.0 RC2.

Comment: I was under the impression that JOGL 2.x wasn't signed with the warning free cert that JOGL 1.x was since it's not being developed directly by sun/oracle any more... as a result it would trigger a security warning. Can it be run totally unsigned? I tried stripping the signing from JOGL 1.x but I think it needs the security permissions to work it's magic (specifically I think it's related to the OS/hardware specific sub-loads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question for the sake of closure: No. Due to security changes in Java since JOGL1 was developed you can't get the access needed without security authorization, and due to the way older things were written specifically JOGL1 it appears you have to bypass java's security entirely to make it work. The end result is JOGL1 is dead dead dead unless you configure java on the specific system to allow any code to run in any way (it breaks even if you authorize it, you have to turn security off entirely, which is obviously a terrible idea and in no way distributable)

Answer (score 1):

If you are distributing JOGL as part of your applet, why aren't you signing it with your certificate?

Or are you trying not to take responsibility for code hosted on your website that you ask your visitors to run?

Comment: Hopefully the maintainers of the trusted library will be able to do a better job of producing secure code (and if they aren't as good, why would you sign that?) and be more widely trusted.

Comment: I'm trying to display 3d content as an element on the page. If the page prompts the user for security authorization to just display a page element they're going to leave and never look back. The sandbox is supposed to provide this sort of functionality safely for java... Guess I have to look into flash.

Comment: Of note the project is also intended to be hosted on multiple sites and integrated in different ways. And applet is being target for it's flexibility, but the security hassles are pretty much killing that.

Comment: @ima747: OpenGL is native code, which runs outside the Java sandbox.  There's no technical way to guarantee its good behavior, it simply has to be trusted.  Which is why you sign it and the user is prompted to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

How about using WebGL? Since WebGL is fully integrated into the DOM you can use it also from a Java applet.

Comment: I would love to use WebGL but it's not supported by much at this point. In a year when it's standardized and average users have upgraded their browsers it will be viable but for now it's not a standard feature that can be relied on.

Comment: @ima747: Huh? All the major browsers already support it in their recent versions.

Comment: Current Safari on mac (critical for my project) does not just as a start off. According to wikipedia only Chrome and Firefox support it in their current release, Safair and Opera support it in development versions and there is no mention of IE. Additionally there is zero backwards compatibility since it's a new standard.